# resolve urls for a django web app

Tags: python, django, url

I've a live website built on Django and hosted on AWS. It's not resolving the urls the way I'd like them to be.

For some reasons if I type `example.com/docprofile/21` in the browser it resolves to `www.example.com` instead of `www.example/docprofile/21`

Although, all the following properly resort to `www.example.com`:

- `http://www.example.com`
- `example.com`

I've no idea why the suburl resort to the homepage.

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^index/$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^404/$', views.error404, name='error404'),
    url(r'^privacy/$', views.privacy, name='privacy'),
    url(r'^terms/$', views.terms, name='terms'),
    url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='about'),

    url(r'^signup/$', views.signup_user, name="signup"),
    url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'm1/login.html'}, name="login"),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.logout_user, name="logout"),

    url(r'^doclistings/$', views.doclistings, name='doclistings'),

    url(r'^clinics/$', views.clinicList, name='clinicList'),

    url(r'^search/$', views.searchResults, name='searchResults'),

    url(r'^docprofile/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.showDocProfile, name='showDocProfile'),

    url(r'^docpic/ (?P<id>\d+)/$', views.getDocPicture, name='getDocPicture'),
)
```

Comment: sounds more like a webserver configuration problem...

Comment: Can you post the entire `urls.py`. The first issue that i see is the url pattern ends with slash / where as your browser url doesm't

Comment: It can be because some other url pattern matches the `example.com/docprofile/21` anyway the url in the post won't match this one. so I don't expect `showDocProfiles` to be invoked

Comment: Does `www.example.com/docprofile/21/` work as expected or does it also redirect you to `www.example.com`? Also, does e.g. `example.com/privacy/` redirect to `www.example.com/privacy/`?

Answer (score 0):

The issues is that the browed url doesn't match the regex in the url pattern.

That is, in pattern

```
url(r'^docprofile/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.showDocProfile, name='showDocProfile'),
```

we expect the url to end with `/` ( the `/$` part does that) where as in the browsed url ( `example.com/docprofile/21`) its not so.

The correct url that matches the pattern is

```
example.com/docprofile/21/
```

which will be then handled by `views.showDocProfile`

Comment: example.com/docprofile/21/ doesn't resolve to www.example.com/docprofile/21/ either.

Comment: @JamesL. That is weird. Let me check if some other issues is there

Comment: @JamesL. Is it re-routing back to `index` each time `docprofile` is using?

Comment: not everytime if i do www.example.com/docprofile/29 it resorts to www.example.com/docprofile/29/  it's only when www is not in the url it resorts to www.example.com

Comment: do you have some sort of rule that handles 404 statuses? For instance if a page is not found or the id is not valid what does it happen? Does it redirect to the homepage?

Comment: it renders a 404 page not the homepage.